# Usage of ChartJS v3 with TypeScript and Webpack

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, chart.js, chart.js3

Up until [release 2.9.4](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v2.9.4), I used ChartJS in combination with [@types/chart.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/chart.js) to get all the types for TypeScript support. My working minimal example with Webpack and TypeScript looks as follows:

**package.json:**

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.31",
    "ts-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3",
    "webpack": "^5.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
}
```

**webpack.config.json:**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: "./main.ts",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

**main.ts:**

```
import Chart from "chart.js";

new Chart("chart", {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3'],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Dataset 1",
      data: [1, 2, 3],
    }]
  },
});
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But after updating to [version 3.0.0](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v3.0.0), this doesn't work anymore (I removed [@types/chart.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/chart.js) because [chart.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chart.js) ships its own types since that release):

**npx webpack serve --mode development**

```
ERROR in [...]/chartjs/main.ts
./main.ts 3:4-9
[tsl] ERROR in [...]/chartjs/main.ts(3,5)
      TS2351: This expression is not constructable.
  Type 'typeof import("[...]/chartjs/node_modules/chart.js/types/index.esm")' has no construct signatures.
```

But since the inbuilt class `Chart` does in fact have a [constructor](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/e1ddaa89926629a04e5dd66bb20fd5c67d501d0f/types/index.esm.d.ts#L451), I don't really understand the problem and how to fix it. What is the intended way of using ChartJS version 3 in combination with Webpack and TypeScript?

Thanks in advance for any tip which leads me into the right direction here!

Comment: Did you import and register the controllers, elements, scales and plugins? https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html#bundlers-webpack-rollup-etc

Comment: @uminder Thank you so much, that was exactly the problem. Considering how much time I spent reading the docs, I'm a bit embarrassed right now :)
If you post your comment as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chart.js 3 is [tree-shakeable](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/), so it is necessary to import and register the controllers, elements, scales and plugins you are going to use.

> Please take a look at [Bundlers (Webpack, Rollup, etc.)](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html#bundlers-webpack-rollup-etc) from the Chart.js documentation.